# Optional parameter at the end effects the label parameter before

Tags: ocaml

Why does `let f ~x ?(y = 1) = x - y;;` make the label for argument `x` become necessary? In other words, when I tried to evaluate `f 3 ~y:2;;`, I received this error:

```
Error: The function applied to this argument has type x:int -> int
This argument cannot be applied without label
```

What's the reason behind such design?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to label the argument x:

```
let g = f 0
```

works and returns a function `g` of type `?y:int -> int`.

To understand this behaviour, it is best to remember that the generic rule is that
labels are mandatory when applying a function.

However, there is a specific rule for total application: if a function is applied to as many non-optional arguments as possible, then labels can be omitted.

A typical example would be

```
let f ~a ~b c d ~e f ~g = a + b + c + d + e + f + g
let x = f 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Going back to your case, your function `f` takes at most one non-optional argument. It is thus considered as totally applied when applied to exactly one argument.

Another important point is that optional arguments are only send to the function once a subsequent positional argument has been sent. This explains why the variable `g` is still a function: no positional arguments were provided to `f` thus the optional argument `?y` was never sent to `f`.

Applied to more complex example

```
let f ~a ?(b=0) c ~d e ~f ~g ?(h=0) = a + b + c + d +e + f + g + h 
 (* there are 8 arguments, 2 optional *)
 (* g is applied to the full 6 non-optional arguments, thus total *)
let g = f 1 3 4 5 6 7
```

the type of `g` is `?h:int -> 0`. Indeed, the application is total, thus all non-optional arguments have been provided. Then, the first optional argument `?b` was followed by a positional argument. It was then provided to the function. However, the last optional argument `?h` has not been yet triggered and is still here.

This behavior implies that optional argument are only useful if there is at least one positional argument after them, as advised by the compiler itself:

```
let f ~x ?(y=0) = x + y;;
Line 1, characters 11-14:
Warning 16: this optional argument cannot be erased.
```